# Java Program to Import a Project When Called

Tags: java, import

I'm using NetBeans to create a menu program so that when a user inputs a number such as 1 through 4 it will essentially import/call that project according to its number assignment. So if a user enters 1 it will run whichever program I have associated with 1. I'm just struggling on how I would go about importing these projects into this Menu program that I'm creating.

Here is what I have so far:

public class Menu {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number 1-4: ");
    int n = reader.nextInt();
}

}
```

Here is one of the projects that I want the program to import:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
int[] array = new int [100];

//Elements in the array are looped one by one using for loop.
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    boolean isPrime = true;

    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++){

        if(i % j==0){
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

// Displays prime numbers of the array
    if(isPrime)

        System.out.println(i + " is a prime number ");
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code to understand what you are struggling.?

Comment: I'm really in the pre-stages right now. So I have a project I called Menu and it's just barebones. I have the other programs built I'm just looking to see how I would go about importing them into my Menu project when a user calls a number.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can simply ask anything. You need to put something by which we can correct you.

Comment: I've added what I have so far. What it needs to do next is load a project depending on the number entered.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to do something like this. Take your 4 or so "projects" and create individual classes that solve whatever problems are involved. Then in your Main program at the top import those classes (if they are not already in the same package). Then use a switch statement. For case(1) new up the appropriate object and call the requisite methods. Same for all the rest. By asking more specific and focused questions, you can get more detailed answers.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Holman. I've added one of the programs that I'd like to import in my posting.

Comment: No problem -- If you find someones answers or comments helpful, it's customary here on StackOverflow to click on the little up arrow.  Everything is gamified, that is, based on points here :)  How is the assignment coming along?

Comment: It's going pretty well actually. Running into an error in one of the cases in my switch statement. It's returning "unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Comment: means you need a try catch block or have to add 'throws XYZException to the method'... If it's still an issue be a bit more specific - include the entire method or class in question - and we'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can’t call the projects, what you can do is you can create a build for that projects(JAR/WAR) and use them in your main project. Then you can use the respective bootstrapper/main class of that four projects by putting them in the switch case and call what ever is required.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Something like this is what I meant when I said turn it into a class yoiu can instantiate in your main menu program.  Use the new operator to create an object and the doWork method will be called when the object is created.

```
 public class Project {
        private int[] array;

        public Project() {
            this.array = new int[100];
            doWork();
        }

        public void doWork() {
            for(int i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++){
                boolean isPrime = true;

                for (int j = 2; j < i; j++){

                    if(i % j==0){
                        isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
                }

            // Displays prime numbers of the array
            if(isPrime)
                    System.out.println(i + " is a prime number ");
            }
        }
    }
```